# Annoying icon in AUCTeX mode

Tags: macos, emacs, latex, auctex

I compiled the recent AUCTeX (11.86) with GNU Emacs 23 on Mac OS X. Everything works perfect, except annoying icon in toolbar (circled in red on the figure below).

[image: AUCTeX toolbar]

I suppose this is a "separator" between native Emacs icons (open file, save file, cut, paste, etc.) and AUCTeX related icons (pdflatex, bibtex, preview, etc.). But isn't this separator a bit too wide? I also check this behavior on my Linux machine, where this icon is only around 1px wide.

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: Still broken? Try asking on latex.stackexchange.com...